# Making ls aware of "hidden" file flag

Tags: macos, terminal.app, ls

Is it possible to make `ls` aware of the `hidden` file flag on Mac OS X?

Currently, a simple `ls -lO` produces:

```
$ ls -lO
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@  84 danielbeck  staff  -      2856 29 Mai 22:44 Applications
drwx------+ 158 danielbeck  staff  -      5372 29 Mai 15:27 Desktop
drwx------@ 250 danielbeck  staff  -      8500 30 Mai 20:40 Documents
drwx------+  11 danielbeck  staff  -       374 29 Mai 22:21 Downloads
drwx------@  84 danielbeck  staff  -      2856 29 Mai 22:48 Library
drwx------@   3 danielbeck  staff  hidden  102  3 Apr 20:45 Movies
drwx------@   5 danielbeck  staff  hidden  170  3 Apr 20:45 Music
drwx------+ 215 danielbeck  staff  -      7310 29 Mai 22:54 Pictures
drwxr-x---@   7 danielbeck  staff  hidden  238  3 Apr 20:45 Public
drwxr-xr-x@   4 danielbeck  staff  hidden  136 24 Apr 23:25 Sites
```

So we have three kinds of visibility: regular, visible files, files with the `hidden` file flag, that aren't actually hidden in Terminal, and *really* hidden files whose names start with a dot.

Is there a way, e.g. using an alias or a reliable shell function, to make `ls` treat `hidden` flagged and `.dothidden` files the same, i.e. hide by default and show with `ls -A` or `ls -a`, similar to how Finder behaves depending on the value of `defaults read com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles`?

<sup>I am aware that `man chflags` specifically mentions `hidden` flag only hides from GUI, i.e. Finder.</sup>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are the steps to get an OS X `ls` which hides files with the *hidden* flag unless the `-a/-A` option is specified, similar to dot files.

1. Install Xcode. I am using Xcode 4.5.1 below.
2. Download your OS release's `libutil` and `file_cmds` from http://www.opensource.apple.com. There's a download button on the right side of each package list entry. This guide was written for OS X 10.8.2, YMMV with the exact steps below if you're on a different version.
3. Extract both archives.
4. Open the `file_cmds.xcodeproj` in Xcode and select to build the `ls` target.

   [image: Screenshot]
5. Select the `file_cmds` Xcode project on the left, and select the `ls` target in the main area. In the *Build Settings* tab, look for *Header Search Paths* in the *Headers* category and add the path to the folder to where you extracted `libutil`.

   [image: Screenshot]
6. Open the file `print.c` in the `ls` folder on the left, and remove the line that says `#include <membershipPriv.h>`. Save the file afterwards. This *should* break something, because includes are there for a reason, but I haven't yet determined what it is.
7. Open the file `ls.c` in the same folder, and look for a comment saying `/* Only display dot file if -a/-A set. */` in the `display` function. Replace it and the condition below it with the following:

   ```
   /* Only display dot file and file with hidden flag if -a/-A set. */
   sp = cur->fts_statp;
   if (((sp != NULL && (sp->st_flags & 0x8000)) || cur->fts_name[0] == '.') && !f_listdot) {
       cur->fts_number = NO_PRINT;
       continue;
   }
   ```
8. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> to build.

   [image: Success!]
9. Select *Products* on the left (end of the folder list) and right-click `ls`. Select *Show in Finder*.

   [image: Build Output folder screenshot]
10. Move the `ls` executable somewhere convenient, e.g. your home directory. Then open Terminal and run `sudo mv $HOME/ls /bin/ls`, or, even better, create a new folder named `bin` in your home directory and move it there. Add that folder to your `PATH` afterwards.

Testing the result:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ touch foo bar
$ chflags hidden bar
$ /bin/ls -lO
total 0
-rw-r--r--@ 1 danielbeck  staff  hidden 0 25 Okt 22:25 bar
-rw-r--r--  1 danielbeck  staff  -      0 25 Okt 22:25 foo
$ $HOME/bin/ls -lO
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 danielbeck  staff  - 0 25 Okt 22:25 foo
$ $HOME/bin/ls -A
bar foo
```

Comment: A wonderful answer!

Comment: At present, http://www.opensource.apple.com/ does not have downloads for macOS Big Sur (versions 11 and higher).